# Кастомный Toolbar пересекается с содержимым Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-toolbar

При использовании кастомного Toolbar'а, содержимое Activity пересекается с ним, будто бы тулбара нету. Проблему можно исправить добавлением отступов (**marginTop**) для верхних компонентов Activity. Мне кажется, это неправильный выход. В коде вопроса ниже **margin**'ы не прописаны, чтобы было видно проблему.

Начало файла **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="me.annenkov.translator.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/swapLanguage"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/swap_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstLanguage"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/swapLanguage"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondLanguage"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/swapLanguage"/>
```

Инициализация тулбара в **onCreate** класса **MainActivity**:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Выглядит это дело так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чёрный текст и иконка-стрелки должны быть ниже тулбара, а не сливаться с ним. В чём дело?

Comment: Какая тема приложения используется?

Comment: @post_zeew Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте просто поместил бы три кнопки в какой нибудь новый layout (например, Relativelayout), а затем просто бы в этом новом layout'е добавил атрибут android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main" (разместить под тулбаром).

Answer (score 2):

Я эту тему тоже особо не исследовал, это еще то "болото", но проблемы этой у меня нет, я делал так, видимо все дело в `CoordinatorLayout`+`AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

           // ...
</RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navside_main_new"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navside_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Естественно, `NavigationView` не обязателен, а значит и `DrawerLayout` тоже, думаю можно их убрать, просто мне они нужны.